# Syntax error in Sql while trying to pull data from other table

Tags: mysql

I have a table '#__usedcar_categories' which has

1 id

2 cat_name

3 state

also a field in other table v_make whose value exactly matches with id in #__usedcar_categories table

Getting Syntax Error

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$c = $item->v_make;
$query = "SELECT #__usedcar_categories.cat_name as cat_name 
  from #__usedcar_categories 
  where #__usedcar_categories.id = $c";

$db->setQuery($query);                                  
$results = $db->loadObjectList();  
foreach($results as $row){
   echo $row->cat_name;
}
 ?>
```

Trying to generate cat_name instead of id
However - despite trying a lot getting message 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Can anyone help as unable to solve after lot of tries

Comment: Please improve your title. Questions need to be useful for future visitors

Comment: have you tried checking what '$c' returns? there might be a datatype mismatch.

Comment: @RahulSharma The value in $c as referred exactly matches with id. Its been checked already

Comment: @juergend - Ok, tried improving the question title. Can you help in with answer of the question as asked too. thanks

Comment: I don't mean the actual value of id but the datatype. because the query seems to be really simple, the only thing I can see that might be causing the problem is a datatype mismatch. so `#__usedcar_categories.id` is integer while `$c` might be returning a character/string

Comment: might be yes, as i observed a single value mis-match in in both and due to same error was happening. after removing same, able to generate data. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a table or column name contains special characters, you need to quote it with backticks. `#` is a special character.

```
$query = "SELECT `#__usedcar_categories`.cat_name as cat_name 
  from `#__usedcar_categories` 
  where `#__usedcar_categories`.id = $c";
```